# Data binding in Polymer

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I have this function which gives me a JSON return value when it is called.

```
getJSON function(url, success){
var ud = '_' + +new Date,
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
               || document.documentElement;
        window[ud] = function(data) {
            head.removeChild(script);
            success && success(data);
        };
        script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
        head.appendChild(script);
}
```

And to call the function, I use the following code.

```
getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey={APIKEY}', function(data){
          //Stuff to be done with the data
        });
```

And then I have a paper card to which I want to bind the JSON value that I get.

```
<paper-card heading="Card Title">
      <div class="card-content">{{json}}</div>
</paper-card>
```

What I want to do is that call that declare the getJSON function the polymer way, call the function and set the JSON value returned to the `{{json}}` data element in the paper card. I have tried more than 5 ways of doing the above but I could not do what I wanted to. I am new to polymer so please help me.

Comment: did you consider using the `<iron-ajax>` element instead of writing this getJSON function? https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax. You can use a computed binding to create the URL for the request.

Comment: @LeBird how can it be done? I am having a difficulty doing the data binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing your own `getJSON()` method, you could use Polymer's `<iron-ajax>` element to fetch the data for you.

The News API [data](https://newsapi.org/#apiArticles) looks similar to this JSON object:

```js
{
  "status": "ok",
  "source": "the-next-web",
  "sortBy": "latest",
  "articles": [{
    "author": "TNW Deals",
    "title": "4 offers from TNW Deals you won’t want to miss",
    "description": "We’ve featured some great offers from TNW …",
  }, {
    "author": "Bryan Clark",
    "title": "Amazing 4k video of the Northern Lights",
    "description": "Tune in, and zone out …",
  }]
}
```

And I assume you want to display each article from the `articles[]` array.

The `<iron-ajax>` element could request the data from the News API and store the server response in [`lastResponse`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-lastResponse), which you could bind to a property that could be used in your template.

In the following example, where we see `last-response="{{data}}"`, `<iron-ajax>` will output the News API response into `data` (i.e., like setting `this.data = response`, where `response` is the JSON object above). Given the shape of the data mentioned previously, we know that `data.articles` would access the array of articles, which could be passed to [`dom-repeat`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat) for iteration:

```
<template>
  <iron-ajax url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=|APIKEY|" 
             auto
             last-response="{{data}}">
  </iron-ajax>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data.articles]]">
    <paper-card heading="[[item.title]]">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>[[item.description]]</p>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
</template>
```

Alternatively if you need to manipulate the response imperatively beforehand, you could [setup an event listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events) for the [`<iron-ajax>.response`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#event-response) event. The event detail contains the data in `.response`. You could process/modify that data, and assign results to `this.articles`, which is bound in the `dom-repeat`.

```
<template>
  <iron-ajax url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=|APIKEY|" 
             auto
             on-response="_onResponse">
  </iron-ajax>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[articles]]">
    <paper-card heading="[[item.title]]">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>[[item.description]]</p>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    ...
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      var data = e.detail.response;
      // do something with data...

      // set this.articles for dom-repeat
      this.articles = data;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I actually prefer the JS way of doing it because I am doing some processing with the news articles. Can you show me how I achieve that? Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra See updated answer. I've described how you would setup a handler to process the data.

Comment: So the variable: data would contain the JSON object provided by NewsAPI?

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra Yes

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: I have a question. How do you access the title and description using the data variable and assign  them to var title and var description given that there are numerous titles and description in the JSON data? is it possible to process them one by one? I mean, put the JSON object into a chunk of code and get the code to extract the first title and description and then store it temporarily in var title and description and then move down the JSON object and do the same.